# Mac OSX - Command-Tab to single window only

Tags: macos

The default behavior for Command-Tab is to open all windows of the application that you select.  Is there a way to only go to the most recent window?

For example, let's say I have a text editor open, and several instances of Terminal.  The text editor is the active window currently, and takes up the full screen.  I want to switch to the window of Terminal that I most recently used, and have my text editor keep the rest of my screen space.  If I just Command-Tab, however, I end up with all of my Terminal windows showing up and completely obscuring my text editor.

The only way I have figured out to get to the point where I want is to drag the Terminal window that I care about off to the side of my text editor, and click it while the text editor is active.  This is an incredible hassle though, so I'm looking for a more efficient way to pull this off.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Another option for those of you looking for a much *faster* window switcher, albeit not as feature-rich as something like [witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/), is `contexts`:

- https://contexts.co/

This is currently my task switcher, as the latency in witch drove me crazy.

Comment: After trying many others (Optimal Layout, Witch, etc.), I'm now using Contexts and loving it.

Comment: contexts is offline an no response from it's creator.

Answer (score 3):

I think you really need to use a utility to do this.  I have been using HyperSwitch for some time and it does the trick.

By default HyperSwitch allows you to switch between open windows
using <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>,
and keeps <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the same,
but you can always change that.

I was also looking at the app Witch, but I couldn't bear
to spend $20 (now $14) on an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> replacement.

1. Free – HyperSwitch http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch
2. Paid (free trial available) – Witch http://manytricks.com/witch/

Answer (score 1):

You can for sure, but it entails some sacrifice... like the Function keys on the F1~F12 row. :)

Under System Preferences > Keyboard

First, disable function keys acting as system control shortcuts.

[image: Disable Function Keys as shorcuts]

Next go to the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, select "Keyboard and Screen Input". Check the "Move focus to active or next window" option, which by default uses CTRL-F4 as the keyboard shortcut, and is changeable (info thanks to Daniel Beck!)

[image: Move focus to active or next window with CTRL-F4]

Voila! Use CTRL-F4 to tab to the next window without showing the rest. I hardly use the shortcut keys anyway so this is my default setup for fast window(not application) switching.

Comment: You actually can change these entries' key combinations. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YUEa2.png).

Comment: Oh you are right! Tried double clicking on the box but it didn't register, thus I assumed it was unchangeable. Thanks for the added info.

Comment: The default actually appears to be Control-fn-F4, which works fine even with the shortcut keys still enabled.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not really replicate the behavior of <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, because it **cycles** through windows instead of switching back and forth. There are also [problems with using this right after switching between desktops/spaces](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/7508/214359) (see **dtc**'s comment on the answer).

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted the exact same thing - essentially like a "previous" button on a TV remote. After a bunch of searching, here's a 2020 answer:

HyperSwitch, Witch, and Contexts are now all paid apps that I haven't used but they seem well-liked. I can't say for sure whether they have this specific functionality.

[AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) is a free switching app that imitates some functionality of the windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> command. It has other uses (and IMO is better than the osX <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>), but it can be used specifically for what you're asking.

To set this up, just go to `AltTab > Preferences > Controls > Show windows from` and allow windows from all sources, set your shortcut (I like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>), then go to `AltTab > Preferences > Appearance > Show on` and select "Screen including menu bar". This second selection makes the shortcut consistently function as a "previous" button when used quickly (e.g. instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-(hold)<kbd>;</kbd> just <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-(tap)<kbd>;</kbd>).

FWIW I'm unaffiliated with AltTab, and as far as I can tell they don't ask for or provide a means for financial contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Light switch has this feature(among other features) but it is now discontinued

link: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26812/lightswitch